# Regex Lookarounds, prevent matches before and after

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a regex that I cannot get working right. I am using PCRE (php) to run it.

The regex looks for inch measurements written as fractions using the forward slash to separate the numerator and denominator. ex `1 3/8in` or `19 15/16"`

It would match `12 1/2"` here:

```
A product description with 12 1/2" in it.
```

But I want it NOT to match if the measurement is part of a dimension, ie has an `x` before or after and matches this format: `19 3/4" x 19 5/8"`

Example text that is matching incorrectly:

```
Product description with 19 3/4" x 19 5/8" in it.
```

This matches `5/8"` when it is supposed to ignore all of it because of the `x` in there.

My regex currently knocks off the measure left of the `x`, but only ignores the whole number on the right side. The lookbehind will capture `5/8"` from the example above. I need it to ignore both sides of the dimension and only match measurements that are by themselves. I am using negative look ahead and behind to match the `x`.

Regex:

```
/\s+(?<!x\s)\d*\s?\d+\/\d+"*\s*(in|")(?!\d*\s?x)\s*/i
```

I ran it through regex101.com's debugger and still can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you add few more examples to make question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` trick:

```
(?(DEFINE)(?<measure>
  (?:\d+ \s*)? \d+ / \d+ (?:in|")
))

(?&measure) \s* x \s* (?&measure) (*SKIP)(*FAIL)
| (?&measure)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cK3vV3/1)

The first part defines what's a measure (you can think of it like a function). Then, if we find two measures separated by `x` (`(?&measure) \s* x \s* (?&measure)`) we skip this part of the input string on failure (`(*SKIP)`), and then fail the match (`(*FAIL)`).

The other part of the alternative can then match the single measurements you're interested in.

The second part could also be written as:

```
(?&measure) (?: \s* x \s* (?&measure) (*SKIP)(*FAIL) )?
```

Comment: @Paulo sure, that's why I bothered to implement .NET bindings for it :-)